# Is InkCanvas incompatible with Projection transforms?

Tags: xaml, uwp, inkcanvas

I am currently developing an UWP application where the user draws some shape freely using the `InkCanvas` element. At some point I need to flip the whole canvas 180 degrees as if showing the backside of a card.

To my surprise, applying a `PlaneTransform` with positive `RotationY` to the `InkCanvas` makes the ink just drawn by the user disappear, and all further input is disabled. I can understand disabling the input when the control is undergoing some weird perspective transform. However, I was surprised to find that it also stops drawing the already existing strokes.

As soon as the `PlaneTransform`'s `RotationY` property returns to zero, the existing strokes come back and input starts working again.

Is this a known issue? Do I need to convert the strokes in the `InkCanvas` to a fixed `UIElement` before applying a projection effect on the drawn shape?

Comment: I'd think `InkCanvas` just does not support projection transform.